# Not able to call method in a gem

Tags: ruby, rubygems

This might be an easy question but I was unfortunately not able to find the answer on Google.

**Context:**
I am working on a project of my own, and I am externalizing some code in a gem (FrenchTaxSystem). It is the first I create a gem and I have difficulties using it properly.

**Problem:**
When calling a method (like testit) defined in the main file (french_tax_system.rb) of my gem I get a "NoMethodError: undefined method `testit' for FrenchTaxSystem:Module", though I can call constants from this same file  (like FISCAL_NB_PARTS_FOR_MARRIED_COUPLE) and it puzzles me.

E.g in IRB I get that when calling a method:
[[image: irb error1]
And it is the same in my Rspecs tests inside my gem
[image: rspec error]

However when calling a constant I have no error:
[image: irb working for constants]

**Main file in my gem:**
french_tax_system.rb

```
module FrenchTaxSystem
  class Error < StandardError; end

  # Constants
  ...
  FISCAL_NB_PARTS_FOR_MARRIED_COUPLE = 2
  ...

  # Methods
  ## Main method
  def testit
    "test me"
  end
end
```

**Gem file structure:**
[image: gem file structure]

Thank you in advance for your help,
Mth0158

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
module FrenchTaxSystem
  def self.testit
    "test me"
  end
end
```

Comment: or `def self.testit`

Comment: Yes right... I was so stuck in my problem that I did not realize I was not using the right syntax since I am calling the method as 'module method'... Thank you very much @romainsalles & @SergioTulentsev